# I want to create a custom visualforce record detail page

Tags: visualforce

I want to create a custom visualforce record detail page. For Example: if we click on Account tab and After that we click on a Account Record than a new page is open. I want to create this page with custom object and visualforce page. Please help me....

Comment: have you done anything so far? or are just looking for documentation links?

Comment: actually i have created a custom object. and also put some record and attachment in this. now i am searching visualforce tag to show the record and attachment at its detail page like standard object. please help me

Comment: The tag you are looking for is <apex:detail> and details are given in the answers below. 
@Jenny B even has a code snippet in his answer. 
Mark an answer as accept if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looing for the apex:detail tag, explained [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_detail.htm).

> apex:detail
>   The standard detail page for a particular object, as
>   defined by the associated page layout for the object in Setup. This
>   component includes attributes for including or excluding the
>   associated related lists, related list hover links, and title bar that
>   appear in the standard Salesforce application interface.
>
> Example

```
<!-- For this example to render properly, you must associate
> the Visualforce page  with a valid account record in the URL.  For
> example, if 001D000000IRt53 is the account ID, the resulting URL
> should be:  https://Salesforce_instance/apex/myPage?id=001D000000IRt53
> See the Visualforce Developer's Guide Quick Start Tutorial for more
> information. -->
>                         
>     <apex:page standardController="Account">    
>         <apex:detail subject="{!account.ownerId}" relatedList="false" title="false"/> 
>     </apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are asking for apex:detail tag
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_detail.htm
https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_tabs.htm